# Testing a hockey puck SCR

Tags: diodes, scr

I have a hockey puck SCR in my circuit which I suspect might be faulty. The reason I suspect the SCR is that while my system is charging up it discharges prematurely and arcs.

I tested it with an multimeter, and the resistance from gate to cathode is OK (11 Ω), but the resistance between cathode and anode is constantly changing between 0.85-14 MΩ. The reverse polarity seems alright and is 1.5 MΩ.

I should add that I did the diode test by multimeter, and both polarities shows OL, open!

Do you think something might be wrong with this SCR and are there any other tests that you could suggest to find out if the problem of my circuit is caused by the SCR?
The capacitor charges up to 900 V, the SCR used in the circuit is,  [ST700C18L0](https://www.vishay.com/docs/94413/vs-st700clseries.pdf), and I don't know much about the current, and even tough in the schematic there are D1,D2,D3 diodes in the actual box there is no diodes and to protect the DC converter I added a series 50K resistor. The SCR is pressed between two heavy copper plates and the plates are bolted by silicon connecting pieces so they stay isolated from each other. And the trigger voltage is 300V.
[image]

Comment: Which SCR are you using? What current and voltage does it handle? How are you mounting it? How are you triggering it? What kind of circuit are you using it in?